# C# type parameter where T is not [insert type here]

Tags: c#, types, constraints

Just wondering if you could constraint the type parameter on a class or a method in c# to be anything but some type. Googled and nothing seems to come up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of "wondering" please provide a specific example of a problem you are trying to solve and where you are stuck. The rest is contained in the C# Language Specification.

Comment: How would that be useful?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You can see a list of [valid type constraints on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d5x73970.aspx).